# Not able to import python packages installed offline via conda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

> Unable to import offline python packages (ModuleNotFoundError).

I have the packages offline which I have installed using `conda install`. 
I am doing everything in the base environment only. The Python version (`which python`) points to the right path. However, as I said, while importing packages are not found.

When I run `conda list`, I see the following in front of my offline installed packages.

> scipy                     1.1.0            py36hc28095f_0
>   **unknown**

Comment: Please add the output of `import sys; sys.path` to your question.

Comment: ['', '/app/localstorage/anaconda3/lib/python37.zip', '/app/localstorage/anaconda3/lib/python3.7', '/app/localstorage/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/app/localstorage/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages']